# Number combination generator

Tags: discord.js

How can I create a command to generate this type of pattern:
For example, if I give them the numbers "1", "2", "3". The combinations result:

1,2,3
1,2,-
1,3,-
2,3,-
1,-,-
2,-,-
3,-,-

Comment: I found a solution after a quick google search. Please put in the minimum research effort before asking a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a recursive solution:

```js
function getCombinations(chars) {
  var result = [];
  var f = function(prefix, chars) {
for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
  result.push(prefix + chars[i]);
  f(prefix + chars[i], chars.slice(i + 1));
}
  }
  f('', chars);
  return result;
}

console.log(getCombinations([1, 2, 3]))
```